# Retrieve all my AWS Secret Manager in my Fargate Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-secrets-manager

I'm using AWS ECS service to run my Docker containers (4 containers)

Also used Secret Manager for storing and retrieve Environment Variables.

I would like to pass my secret manager ARN.  So the containers will access all my env vars without adding `key=value` in my task definition again. (avoid repeating my self)

I Googled and I found the following solution, but I'm not sure if it's what I'm looking for:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:MySecretName"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to avoid:
`
I want to avoid :

```
"secrets": [
    {
        "name": "MySecretEnvVariable1",
        "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:MySecretName"
    },
    {
        "name": "MySecretEnvVariable2",
        "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:aws_account_id:secret:MyOtherSecret"
    }
]
```

Expected:
I don't want to repeat my self by entering `key=value` in the task definition again, since all my secrets are already in AWS Secret Manager, I want to pass the ARN and the container should be able to access my secrets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That IAM policy you included in your question would indeed give the ECS task permission to access the secret in SecretsManager, as long as you included that IAM policy in the ECS Task Execution Role.

That just gives it permission though. To have ECS pass the actual secret value into your container, you need to [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/secrets-envvar-secrets-manager.html) the `secrets` in the task definition and then ECS will pass the value of those secrets into the container as environment variables.

---

Regarding your updated question:

If all you want to do is provide the code in your container the *permission* to access your secrets, then include that IAM policy in the ECS Task Role (not the task execution role). And include the Secret ARN as a regular environment variable string, not as an ECS Secret.

Then your code will be responsible for taking the ARN from the environment variable, and calling the AWS SecretsManager API (via the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/) for the programming language you are using) to pull in those secret values.

Comment: first thank you for the answer,  can you explain a little more please
`
you need to configure the secrets in the task definition and then ECS will pass the value of those secrets into the container as environment variables.
`

my goal is to avoid passing individual key=value .

Question updated

Comment: Please read the link I posted to the official documentation on this topic to understand how this feature works. If you simply pass the ARN of the secret as an environment variable, than that single variable will end up holding the JSON representation of all the values in that secret. Your code running in the container will then have to parse that and pull out the individual values. Otherwise you can configure multiple environment variables, one for each secret value.

Comment: It sounds like you may be doing this via the AWS web console or something, since you are trying to saving yourself from typing a lot? If that is the case then you should really look into an infrastructure as code (IaC) tool such as CloudFormation or Terraform to manage this for you. I highly recommend using Terraform for this sort of thing.

Comment: What do you think about :

Comment: @DockerIssues I've updated my answer, per your updated question.

Comment: please check my suggested answer

Comment: @DockerIssues that answer you propose should work, it's what my updated answer is, just using the AWS CLI instead of the SDK like I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about the following solution :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the name of the specific Secret Manager
SECRET_MANAGER_NAME="YourSecretManagerName"

# Retrieve a list of secrets from the specific Secret Manager
SECRET_NAMES=$(aws secretsmanager list-secrets --output json --query "SecretList[?Tags[?Key=='SecretManager' && Value=='$SECRET_MANAGER_NAME']].Name")

# Loop through the secret names and fetch their values
for SECRET_NAME in $SECRET_NAMES; do
    SECRET_VALUE=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $SECRET_NAME --query SecretString --output text)
    # Extract the secret name without the prefix
    ENV_VAR_NAME=$(basename $SECRET_NAME)
    # Set the secret value as an environment variable
    export $ENV_VAR_NAME="$SECRET_VALUE"
done

# Execute your main application process here
exec "$@"
```